# How can I watch an AVI file on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, video

I understand that the bundled apps for iPhone does not support AVI files. However, I have lots of these files which I want to watch on my iPhone.

Can you suggest a streamlined, automatic way of doing this? I have never watched videos on my iPhone or iTunes before and would appreciate step by step answers.

Answer (score 5):

Use [HandBrake](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/WindowsGuiGuide) to easily convert the AVI files to an iPhone compatible format then sync those converted files with your iPhone

Or, email/post them to [Posterous](http://posterous.com), and they'll be auto-converted into a format watchable on your iPhone

Comment: Handbrake ftw..

Comment: Handbrake ftl.. doesn't work with MKV + embedded subs

Comment: I encode MKV all the time in Handbrake. . . but not with subs. Hmmm I didn't know that.

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of apps which will allow your iPhone to support .avi files...

For starters, there is the all-time favorite [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html) **(free)** . You get the file-support and the friendly user interface like you're used to on your Mac.

Then there is [AcePlayer](http://itunes.apple.com/be/app/aceplayer/id463242636?mt=8) **($2.99)** which will even support more files, is extremely user friendly and this app is close to my favorite.

But my all time favorite app is [CineX-Player](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cinexplayer-the-best-way-to/id391790896?mt=8) **($1.99)**. 
They tend to do some actions where you can get this app with a discount (or even free).

All of these apps are easily managed by iTunes File Sharing:

[image]

They all support a lot of files (including your requested .avi), subtitles and they all have a nice and clear interface. I can highly recommend CineX-Player, but VLC is great as well and it's free!

Comment: VLC is no longer available on the AppStore

Comment: Checking it now, July 30, it's available in the AppStore @hellothere. (:

Comment: VLC was able to play my AVI's on iPad. Feb 28, 2016

Answer (score 1):

Quicktime will do this too: *File* → *Save as* and then choose **iPhone** from the format list.

Comment: Brilliant, my QuickTime Player had the *File > Export* Option

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of apps that support this. The best I've found is **yxplayer in the app store** or **yxflash from Cydia** (same thing for free, but requires jailbreak) -- good compatability, fast with non-HD content, etc. You can move the files over using either iTunes or any program that let's you access the filesystem like [iPhoneBrowser](http://code.google.com/p/iphonebrowser/), then watch them without the need for any conversions.

Conversion is not a good option:

- Slow (often about 2/3 the length of the video, so you need to plan ahead)
- Lossy (you will lose quality)
- Larger files (usually)
- Generally a pain in the ass

If you must convert, HandBrake (like the accepted answer suggests) is good but doesn't support all formats - [xvid4psp](http://www.winnydows.com/) in my experience is slightly better.

If you want to convert MKV files with embedded ASS/SSA subtitles (having spent >5 hours looking for a program that will work for this), version 4 of xvid4psp (doesn't work on Win7 x64) is the *only* program that will do this. v5/v6 of xvid4psp, HandBrake, etc, etc. will not work.

Comment: How can I import incompatible video files into iTunes anf then move them to my iPhone? Everytime I try to drop an avi file into iTunes, I get the "forbidden" mouse cursor.

Comment: @Martin - Once you get yxplayer, go to iTunes, go to your iphone/ipad on the left tree, and choose the "Apps" tab from the top. Scroll down a bit to "File Sharing" (that says "Documents" right under it), and click "yxplayer" from the list of apps. Then you can transfer documents from your computer (though you need to use another tool to transfer folders).  Yeah, it's not that discoverable a feature, but Apple doesn't like things that aren't Apple.

Comment: There is no "File Sharing" section in the Apps tab. Does the iPhone need to be jailbroken for that?

Comment: @Martin - No it doesn't need to be jailbroken. A picture says 1000 words; I made a guide: http://nv3wrg.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pYB8jO58xlRA2GUJBVxkQGGn3XavcPplPGKMemWQn7Bk6bxAYNYcaX5dR9wLxDJFH47adWdmO7Z2_rAprAcHQfFlpafL4dwsz/itunes_ui_sucks.png?psid=1

Comment: Thank you very much, Robert (+1 for the tutorial). In now know, why I don't see the file sharing section. At the time I asked before, the app was not yet installed, but only downloadad. And when I tried to install it, I had to face the fact that it cannot be installed on my iPod touch. Shame on me. The iPhone is ordered, and I will definitely try this app.

Comment: "vlc for iphone" is another option which is available through cydia.

Answer (score 0):

Buzzplayer from the App Store plays AVI files and even embeds srt subtitles.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the app you mention in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [**flex:player**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flex-player/id451024857?mt=8) for iPad, iPhone (3GS and above), and iPod touch (3rd gen. and above).

flex:player will play the AVI file **without conversion**. You simply have to transfer the file.

[image: Flex player]

To transfer the AVI file, you can use [**iTunes file sharing**](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4094).

[image: iTunes file sharing]

Bear in mind that, depending on your device, you might experience stuttering if the video is HD. The iPhone 4 and above should be able to handle 720p content just fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest  [VLC for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vlc-for-ios/id650377962?mt=8). AVI is a "container" for many different video formats (codecs). VLC could be a good viewer for many of the different video formats that AVI supports. When starting the VLC for the first time it has a good wizard that tells you what to do step by step.

This is a brief step by step way of doing it:

1. Download VLC for iOS in Appstore on your iPhone
2. Connect your phone to your computer
3. Open iTunes on your computer
4. Select the iPhone icon
5. Select Apps Scroll down to File Sharing
6. Select VLC
7. In VLC Documents click Add... and upload your AVI file
8. Open VLC on your iPhone
9. Select All Files
10. Click your AVI file